# Weird drop-shadow on certain backgrounds

Tags: html, css, dropshadow

I applied a drop-shadow filter on my clip-path, while the shadow works well on white background, it does not work at all on a darker one (example below) -
[image]

It just looks like some weird lines instead of a blurred shadow, The shadow is a bit darker then the background, making the shadow completly black makes it work at the start of the shadow but to the end it has these lines once again.
The code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 2000px;
}

body .headerText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 40vw;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 8vh;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}

body .headerWrap {
  position: fixed;
  filter: drop-shadow(-30px -30px 60px #363636) drop-shadow(-30px -30px 90px #414141);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-30px -30px 60px #363636) drop-shadow(-30px -30px 90px #414141);
}

body .headerWrap header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 40% 0%, 28% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 40% 0%, 28% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -webkit-animation: rotate 1s 1;
          animation: rotate 1s 1;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
          animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -3s);
          animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -3s);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  to {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 20% 0%, 14% 100%, 0% 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 20% 0%, 14% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 20% 0%, 14% 100%, 0% 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 20% 0%, 14% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}

body .landing {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

body .content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: #424242;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="headerText"><h1>Hello bruddas</h1></div>
    <div class="headerWrap">
        <header></header>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            document.body.style.setProperty('--scroll',window.pageYOffset / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight));
          }, false);
    </script>
    <div class="landing"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: do you want something like this drop-shadow (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOcOO.png) ?

Comment: Not really but it might be the only thing to save it here, or just get rid of the shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

The shadow works fine on both colors.

1. You can barely (or not...) see it, but it's there.
2. The lines are in fact the shadow.

The problem here, is the **low amount of colors** rendered by the screen due to the **low contrast** between the darkest and lightest colors (for the dark one).

Screens have a limited amount of colors. It also depends on the screen type and settings, sometimes you can easily see it (and it's ugly), sometimes you can barely notice that behavior (you just see a smooth gradient).

### Example

Here is an example:

[image: example]

Notice I used the **same shadow for both sides**.

You should be able to see the lines on darker tones (the top of the left side, and all the right side). Maybe you cannot see the lines at all, again, it depends on the output device and settings.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't get this to really work?

Comment: It actually works, may not be what you spect. On UI design, we tend to define a different shadow colors for dark and light backgrounds. Unfortunately you have just one color for both.